# Jboss EAP 7 - How to exclude implicit modules from deployment (javax.jms)?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I didn't think I would end up here but after a lot of Google and StackOverflow searches here I'm.

[This is my exact problem](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tale-two-jars-marco-antonio-almeida-silva) except that I can't afford to make code changes.

The WAR I'm trying to deploy includes a JMS library (i.e. *javax.jms*, which I cannot exclude form the WAR.) which is already loaded by Jboss EAP 7 by default. The path to `jar` is something like this `jboss/modules/system/layers/base/javax/jms/api/ain/jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final-redhat-1.jar`. Because of this two different versions of the same classes loading I'm getting *ClassCastException*.

```
org.apache.activemq-ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory cannot to be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

So, I want Jboss to **NOT** load *javax.jms* so that my application can use the JAR included with the WAR.

So, I was wondering if there was any way to exclude the module globally (for all WAR deployments).

Excluding it per deployment would work too. And I do realize it can be acheivd using *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure
        xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="javax" />
            <subsystem name="javax.jms" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure
    xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax" />
            <module name="javax.jms" />
            <module name="javax.jms.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I placed the file in *WEB-INF* directory. It didn't work. It still loaded the JMS class from *modules* folder of Jboss EAP. So, how do I correctly do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but the subsystem name should be `messaging-activemq`, e.g. `<subsystem name="messaging-activemq"/>` in the exclusion. However I'm not sure JMS will work correctly in your deployment unless you also include an implementation.

Comment: hy, you have found a solution?

Comment: @sghaierali I just marked the answer that worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47912334/1175279

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is here:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="messaging-activemq"></subsystem>
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.jms.api"></module>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This way you exclude both messaging subsystem and the JMS api.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the JMS API JAR from your deployment. You can still keep the JMS implementation JAR in your deployment but that should probably end up in a RAR, preferably outside your deployment.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I cannot remove JMS API from my WAR (deployment). Please go through the updated question.

Comment: Sure you can. JBoss provides the JMS API you provide the JMS implementation. No problem.

Comment: If I remove JMS jar from my WAR file, I get `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Destination` error while deploying the WAR.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201243) has some things you could try.

Notably:

> I think the problem is that activemq-all-5.4.2.jar contains javax.jms.*.  Your deployment already gets this implicitly from the javaee.api module (see more information about implicity module dependencies [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments)).  I don't think it is appropriate for an application module/jar to package Java EE interfaces.  You can try simply deleting the javax directory from activemq-all-5.4.2.jar or using a different set of ActiveMQ jars in your module to limit it to only what you need.

and/or altering your `module.xml` for ActiveMQ

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="activemq">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="activemq-all-5.4.2.jar"/>  
    </resources>  
    <dependencies>  
        <module name="javax.api"/>  
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

There appears to be a method to [embed ActiveMQ in Jboss](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EmbedActiveMQInJBossAS7) as well, if you're interested. I won't pull out information from that article, as it doesn't answer the original question.